# Module name prefixes should've been stripped by the native side but wasn't for RCTJSCExecutor

Tags: ios, react-native

*I am integrating `google admob` to my `react-native app` using `react-native-admob.` i am able to build my project but i am getting run time error*

`Module name prefixes should've been stripped by the native side but wasn't for RCTJSCExecutor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I solved this by just restarting react native packager.*